# Traefik 'PathPrefix' is not working as expected for underlying requests

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik

Trying to achieve simple Nginx routing of request in Traefik.
Unfortunately, Traefik's `PathPrefix` is not working out of the box

```
location /app1/ {
    proxy_bind $server_addr;
    proxy_pass http://my-subdomain.localhost/app1/;
}

location /app2/ {
    proxy_bind $server_addr;
    proxy_pass http://my-subdomain.localhost/app2/;
}

location /app3/ {
    proxy_bind $server_addr;
    proxy_pass http://my-subdomain.localhost/app3/;
}
```

Traefik configuration code using docker-compose to spin all the services.

File : `dockercompose.yml`

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  traefik-reverse-proxy:
    container_name: traefik-reverse-proxy
    image: traefik:v2.2
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.reverse-proxy.rule=Host(`my-subdomain.localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/traefik`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.reverse-proxy.service=api@internal"

  app1:
    container_name: app1
    image: registry.gitlab.com/my-hobby-project/app1:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app1.rule=(Host(`my-subdomain.localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/app1`))"
    
  app2:
    container_name: app2
    image: registry.gitlab.com/my-hobby-project/app2:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app2.rule=(Host(`my-subdomain.localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/app2/`))"

  app3:
    container_name: app3
    image: registry.gitlab.com/my-hobby-project/app3:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app3.rule=(Host(`my-subdomain.localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/app3`))"
```

Hint:

A.
App3 is my angular app, in this case, I'm actually able to hit index.html page but underlying resources are getting 404.

First request: `http://staging.localhost/app3` -> finds index.html.

Following request: such as `http://staging.localhost/assests/util.js` -> 404 (I expected traefik should make this request as http://staging.localhost/app3/assests/util.js )

Also I tried using [AddPrefix](https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/addprefix/) but didn't work.

AddPrefix code:

```
 - "traefik.http.routers.app3.rule=Host(`staging.localhost`) && (PathPrefix(`/app3`))"
 - "traefik.http.middlewares.add-app3.addprefix.prefix=/app3"
 - "traefik.http.routers.app3.middlewares=add-app3"
```

B. Also tried with slash at the end of pathPrefix (checkout app2 example code above), unfortunately, it doesn't work too.

C. Using Traefik version 2.2 (See docker-compose.yml file)

> Question:
>
> 1. How can I access the traefik dashboard by using subdomain and pathPrefix i.e. `http://my-subdomain.localhost/traefik`
> 2. How can I access the underlying resources of Angular : [http://my-subdomain.localhost/app3`](http://my-subdomain.localhost/app3%60)

Comment: Similar problem here: https://community.containo.us/t/pathprefix-and-strip/2122/4

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have in your config is that you are overwriting several times the same `app1` router. It think this is why only one of routes is working.

Basically instead of doing this:

```yaml
  app1:
    container_name: app1
    image: registry.gitlab.com/my-hobby-project/app1:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app1.rule=(Host(`my-subdomain.localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/app1`))"

  app2:
    container_name: app2
    image: registry.gitlab.com/my-hobby-project/app2:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app1.rule=(Host(`my-subdomain.localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/app2/`))"

  app3:
    container_name: app3
    image: registry.gitlab.com/my-hobby-project/app3:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app1.rule=(Host(`my-subdomain.localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/app3`))"
```

You should be doing this

```yaml
  app1:
    container_name: app1
    image: registry.gitlab.com/my-hobby-project/app1:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app1.rule=(Host(`my-subdomain.localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/app1`))"

  app2:
    container_name: app2
    image: registry.gitlab.com/my-hobby-project/app2:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app2.rule=(Host(`my-subdomain.localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/app2/`))"

  app3:
    container_name: app3
    image: registry.gitlab.com/my-hobby-project/app3:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app3.rule=(Host(`my-subdomain.localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/app3`))"
```

Also note that brackets are not neeeded around `` (Host(`my-subdomain.localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/app3`)) ``. You could simply do`` Host(`my-subdomain.localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/app3`) ``.

I basically felt into the same traps and Traefik does not easily show the errors. It basically just silently fails...
Next time, enable debugging and look for errors in the logs. I'm showing how to do this in this article: https://juliensalinas.com/en/traefik-reverse-proxy-docker-compose-docker-swarm-nlpcloud/

Hope it solved your problem!

Comment: did not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same difficulty. With containers like whoami, no problem. But with a container like nginx, you need "/nginx" to make sense on the container, as explained in a [PathPrefix and strip discussion](https://community.traefik.io/t/pathprefix-and-strip/2122) by Zespri.
Here is a docker-compose.yml to illustrate my point.

Note the volume shared between the host and the nginx1 container.

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.1"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"

  whoami1:
    image: containous/whoami:v1.5.0
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami1.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami1.rule=Host(`myhost.mydomain.org`) && PathPrefix(`/whoami`)"


  whoami2:
    image: containous/whoami:v1.5.0
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami2.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami2.rule=Host(`whoami.mydomain.org`)"

  nginx1:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx1.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx1.rule=Host(`myhost.mydomain.org`) && PathPrefix(`/nginx`)"

 nginx2:
    image: nginx:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx2.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx2.rule=Host(`nginx.mydomain.org`)"
```

The host's html folder contains an nginx folder which will respond to "/nginx".

```
$ tree html/
html/
└── nginx
    └── index.html
```

If you don't do this sharing between host and container, you will get the following error.

```
$ docker logs traefik_nginx1_1
2021/02/16 13:36:16 [error] 27#27: *1 "/usr/share/nginx/html/nginx/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.24.0.3, server: localhost, request: "HEAD /nginx/ HTTP/1.1", host: "mydomain.org"
```

This way, the 4 queries answer correctly!

```
curl -Ik http://myhost.mydomain.org/whoami
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

curl -Ik http://whoami.mydomain.org
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

curl -Ik http://myhost.mydomain.org/nginx
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

curl -Ik http://nginx.mydomain.org
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```